# Disable .htaccess regeneration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, include

My problem is that I have the VPS login for WHM and cPanel, but no root acces to Linux. What should I do to overule the config that hosting admin created.
Whatever I write in .htaccess, it is instantly replaced with rewrite rules for WordPress.
Is there anything I can add to the path below so I can edit and save the htaccess?

*WHM > Service Configuration > Apache Configuration > Include Editor*

I also must say that this VPS have a few other domains managed by other admins. Therefore, I should limit my new rules only to my domains.

CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 kvm – ns3 **/** WHM 54.0 (build 21)**/**Apache 2.2*

Thanks!

Comment: Emm, if you can access WHM > Service Configuration > Apache Configuration > Include Editor in WHM - this means you do have root access to the VPS.

Comment: You mean I can use the Linux console and rewrite the httpd.conf. Where could I find the command prompt in WHM, Linux has the same password with WHM?

Comment: WHM doesn't have a command prompt, you should connect via SSH. Root password is the same to WHM and to root-level SSH. But you can't simply edit Apache config file if you're using cPanel/WHM because it'll be overwritten. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What you are saying is new and very interesting. I already said what I am trying to do, I think I made myself clear. I suppose there is some override setting in httpd.conf that regenerate the .htaccess. I really don't know how to edit this file, therefore I would use includes. I don't mind if my rules will vanish, I can add the code again after each reboot.

Comment: I can't really imagine an override that will delete anything in .htaccess file and revert it to default WP rules. There should be something else going on. In any case, even the most fancy override can't physically change the contents of .htaccess file.

Comment: I made one important step: installed WinSCP and logged in via SSH, I read the content of httpd.conf. Too bad host admin it's not available. I will search more on the web about this topic. Thank you for the informations so far.

Comment: Well, good luck :) What's still puzzling me is this: "Whatever I write in .htaccess, it is instantly replaced with rewrite rules for WordPress". Did you check permissions and ownership of this file? Maybe it's just not allowing you to save changes to it?

Comment: My words was not chosen right. I rephrase: If I save the htaccess, it is rewritten and permission reverted to 444, even if before it had 644 or other. Stackoverwflow frowns extended discutions... then I'll stop here :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the same as [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185638/how-to-stop-wordpress-from-changing-default-htaccess-permissions-to-444). I also had to spend a few weeks without knowing what about I was looking for. I never made the connection between .htaccess regeneration and malware I couldn't get rid off. OMG :) Thank you stackoverflow!